# 3 months free trial ends on a date

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> Contact us by 1 June 2021 to get a 3-month free trial offer.

Is the above sentence on free trial grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: I would expect 'three months trial' to be counted from the date of the customer's application, not to have a fixed end date.

Comment: The grammar is fine but it is nonsense.

Comment: The offer of the free trial could end on 30/6.  I suspect that is what you mean, but it is not what you have written.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, I have changed the question to make it looks obvious

Comment: @mdeway Thanks, I have changed the question to make it looks obvious

Comment: @JamesK Exactly, I reword it, can you help to relook it again?

Comment: The amended sentence is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect simply "Contact us by 1 June 2021 to get a 3-month free trial."

There is no need to say that an offer is involved, the sentence itself is the offer.